# Geolocation in Internet Explorer vs Other Browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, geolocation

I am doing a pretty simple geolocation inquiry that works great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android and Apple devices.  In IE though the Microsoft location services places my location about 500 miles away.  Here is the script.

```
<button id="getlocal" onclick="getLocation()">Check by my Current Location</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

$("#getlocal").click(function(){
    $("#getlocal").hide();
});

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var json = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + 
    ", " + position.coords.longitude;   

$.getJSON(json, function (json) {

var address = json.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;

var address2 = json.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;

if(address == "LaSalle County" || address == "Grundy County" || address == "Livingston County" || address == "Marshall County" || address == "Putnam County" || address == "Wood ford County" || address == "McLean County" || address == "Bureau County" ){
   x.innerHTML = "<p class=\"green\"><i class=\"material-icons\">thumb_up</i> Based on your current location in " + address + ", <b>you are eligible for membership</b>. Please review all qualifications above to determine if you fully qualify.</p>";
}else if(address2 == "LaSalle County" || address2 == "Grundy County" || address2 == "Livingston County" || address2 == "Marshall County" || address2 == "Putnam County" || address2 == "Woodford County" || address2 == "McLean County" || address2 == "Bureau County" ){
   x.innerHTML = "<p class=\"green\"><i class=\"material-icons\">thumb_up</i> Based on your current location in " + address2 + ", <b>you are eligible for membership</b>. Please review all qualifications above to determine if you fully qualify.</p>";
}else{
  x.innerHTML = "<p class=\"redalert\">Sorry you are not eligible at this time, based on your current location in <b>" + address2 + ", " + address +"</b>. You may still qualify though, please read above to learn more. If this location is wrong please call us at 815-673-5577 to determine your membership status.</p>";
}

});
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to force IE to use Google location services? Or am I stuck with what IE wants to send me?

Comment: add `{enableHighAccuracy: true}` as 3th parameter

Comment: What's the 2nd parameter?

Comment: error callback function

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this.